# How to get HeadQuarter location from wikidata (present on a mapbox) instead of the location of the city

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Hello everyone first question here.

I got this sparql query which take every pharmatical industry in wikidata and return
the headquarter location if it exists.
The problem is the location (lattitude longitude) point to the center of the city instead of where the headquarter is. (For example "Laboratoires Servier" wd:Q907487 lead to the Point(2.226944444 48.871111111) the center of suresnes).
There is a mapbox on the wikidata page https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q907487 which show the correct coordinates: (48°52'24.96"N, 2°13'36.48"E) and i can't find a way to access it.

```
SELECT ?company ?location ?coordo WHERE {
?company (wdt:P452*) wd:Q507443.
OPTIONAL {?company wdt:P159 ?localisation.
          ?localisation wdt:P625 ?coordo}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, your current query gets the coordinates of the headquarter already. And `?location` isn't bound at all in your query, what is its purpose?

Comment: `SELECT ?company ?head_quarter ?head_quarter_coordinates ?head_quarter_coordinates_qualifier WHERE {
?company (wdt:P452*) wd:Q507443.
OPTIONAL {?company p:P159 ?stmt.
          ?stmt ps:P159 ?head_quarter .
          OPTIONAL {?stmt pq:P625 ?head_quarter_coordinates_qualifier .}
          ?head_quarter wdt:P625 ?head_quarter_coordinates
         }
}`